# Jest in Meteor?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, mocha.js, chai, jestjs

I want to run Jest test cases for snapshot testing React components in my Meteor client app.

Install packages:

`npm i --save-dev jest react-test-renderer`

And I simply write something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { expect } from 'meteor/practicalmeteor:chai';
import CoolComponent from '../some/where';


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<CoolComponent />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
}
```

Run the test case:

`meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`

And get this error:

> TypeError: expect(...).toMatchSnapshot is not a function

[image]

I'm not sure how to pick up the jest's version of `expect` to use the `toMatchSnapshot` method

Please help

Comment: What's your jest version ? To be able to use the toMatchSnapshot it has to be at least version 14.

Comment: `"jest": "^20.0.4"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Jest tests with the `practicalmeteor:mocha` driver package. That package runs your tests with Mocha (and Mocha doesn't recognize `.toMatchSnapshot()`.

I've had nominal success running Jest tests by installing the Jest cli...

`npm i -g jest`

...and running the tests from the command line without going through Meteor.

Of course, you will need to mock Meteor's dependencies. For this, I used `jest-meteor-stubs`, but stubbing everything by hand proved to be inhibitive.

Until someone writes an official Jest driver package for Meteor, you might be better off sticking to Mocha.